# Cast value to enum that inherits from Error

Tags: ios, swift, enums, casting

I have a service class that offers several methods that make calls to the backend, and a common theme for those methods is that I can pass callbacks for the success and error cases:

```
func makeCall(onSuccess: @escaping APIResponse, onError: @escaping APIError)
```

The type `APIError` is defined like so:

```
typealias APIError = (Error) -> Void
```

Furthermore I have an enum `APICallError` like this:

```
enum APICallError: Error {

    case insufficientCredentials
    case malformedResponse
    case forbidden

}
```

So in my service methods I can call `onError(response.result.error!)` if the result contained an error object (the force unwrap is just for brevity, I'm not really doing that) and also pass my own enum value if the HTTP result is not specific enough, like `onError(APICallError.insufficientCredentials)`.

This works fine.

The problem is, I can't figure out how to evaluate in my client code whether the `error` parameter that's coming in is of type `APICallError` and which one of those specifically. If I do:

```
if let callError = error as? APICallError {
    if callError == .forbidden {
        // ...
    }
}
```

execution doesn't make it past the typecast. `if error is APICallError` also does not seem to work.

How can I cast the `error` parameter to my `APICallError` enum value that I know is in there, because when I `print(error)` it gives me `myapp.APICallError.forbidden`?

Comment: Can you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Copying your code to a playground worked as expected.

Comment: `if let callError = error as? APICallError` is exactly as it should be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to simulate what you have posted in your question in Playground, and what you are already doing should work fine for you.

`if error is APICallError` is also working. One possibility why the `if let` condition fails might be due to the `error` being `nil`. Check if that is the case by using breakpoints.

```
typealias APIError = (Error) -> Void

//The error type used in your question
enum APICallError: Error {
    case insufficientCredentials
    case malformedResponse
    case forbidden
}


//A different error type for comparison
enum AnotherError: Error {
    case error1
    case error2
    case error3
}

let apiCallError: Error = APICallError.insufficientCredentials
let anotherError: AnotherError  = AnotherError.error1

//Closure definition
var onError: APIError? = { inputError in
    if let apiError = inputError as? APICallError {
        print("APICallError")
    }
    if let anotherError = inputError as? AnotherError {
        print("AnotherError")
    }
}

//Above defined closure is called here below...
onError?(apiCallError)
onError?(anotherError)
```

---

**Console Output (Works as expected):**

```
APICallError
AnotherError
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the enum rawValue constructor.

```
if let callError = APICallError(rawValue: error) {
    if callError == .forbidden {
    ...
    }
} else {
    // was not an APICallError value
}
```

Comment: `enum APICallError: Error` cannot be constructed from a raw value.

Comment: I had the impression the error parameter was coming from http error code. You could always create a method on the enum to return the appropriate type from an http error if the RawRepresentable protocol isn't appropriate.